# Windows shell command to delete numbered files greater than n

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I want to write a windows shell command that goes through all files in a folder with 20 files like:

```
InputFile1.csv
InputFile2.csv
InputFile3.csv
InputFile4.csv
...
InputFile20.csv
```

and I want to delete all files with a file number bigger than 5. That means only `InputFile1` to `InputFile4` should be left in the folder C:\tmp\out

I wrote this command:

```
FOR /R  C:\tmp\out\ %G IN (*) DO 
  FOR /F  %H IN ("%~nG") DO 
    (SET str="%H" && SET lastdigits=%str:~10,2% && IF %lastdigits% GTR 5 del %G)
```

as a result, on the command prompt I get, for each file in the folder:

```
C:\tmp\out>(SET str="InputFile1"   && SET lastdigits= 9   && IF 9 GTR 4 del C:\tmp\out\VisInputFile1.csv )
.......
......
C:\tmp\out>(SET str="InputFile9"   && SET lastdigits= 9   && IF 9 GTR 4 del C:\tmp\out\InputFile9.csv )
```

and all the files are deleted.

Why is `lastdigits` always 9?

This needs to be one shell command, because I want to use this command in a BPEL-Activity.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
cmd /q /e:on /c "(for /l %a in (1 1 4) do set "inputFile%a=1")&for %a in (inputfile*.csv) do if defined %~na (echo keep "%a") else (echo del "%a")"
```

It just defines a variable for each file name to keep and then iterates over the file list checking if a variable with the same name is defined. If it is defined keep the file else remove the file. It is equivalent to

```
for /l %a in (1 1 4) do set "inputFile%a=1"
for %a in (inputfile*.csv) do if defined %~na (
    echo keep "%a"
) else (
    echo del "%a"
)
```

but in one line

For a substring operation and numeric test on the file numbers

```
cmd /q /e:on /v:on /c "for %a in (inputfile*.csv) do (set "n=%~na" & set /a "n=!n:~9!">nul & (if !n! gtr 4 (set "n=") else if !n! lss 1 (set "n=")) & if defined n (echo KEEP "%a") else (echo del "%a"))"
```

For this to work, as the value of the file number is extracted inside a block and processed inside the same block, delayed expansion is needed.

It is equivalent to

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for %a in (inputfile*.csv) do (
    set "n=%~na" 
    set /a "n=!n:~9!">nul 
    if !n! gtr 4 (
        set "n="
    ) else if !n! lss 1 (
        set "n="
    )
    if defined n (echo KEEP "%a") else (echo del "%a")
```

In both cases, delete operations are only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` command that prefixes `del`

**edited** (again, I understood it the wrong way) to adapt to comments : to handle the two ranges and remove the files 1-5, 15-20

First code

```
cmd /q /e:on /c "(for %a in (1 2 3 4 5 15 16 17 18 19 20) do set "inputFile%a=1")&for %a in (inputfile*.csv) do if not defined %~na (echo keep "%a") else (echo del "%a")"
```

Second code

```
cmd /q /e:on /v:on /c "for %a in (inputfile*.csv) do (set "n=%~na" & set /a "n=!n:~9!">nul & set "delete=" & (if !n! leq 5 (set "delete=1") else if !n! leq 20 if !n! geq 15 set "delete=1") & if defined delete (echo del "%a") else (echo KEEP "%a"))"
```

Comment: i do not understand this one ...what is the (114) for? and the =1 ? is the second solution complete? where to put the delayed expansion? Thanks for the answers

Comment: @sakal, `for /l` is a numeric for loop: starting in 1, in steps of 1 up to 4. So, the code generates four variables named `inputfile1`, `inputfile2`, ... the files to keep. For each file if a variable with the same name is defined, it is a file to keep.

Comment: @sakal, Both solutions are complete. The `/v:on` switch is asking cmd to start with delayed expansion active.

Comment: ok thanks, and that for /l loop...can i use a range there too? something like for /l % a in (1 1 5) | (15 1 20) ??

Comment: @sakal, no, `for /l` does not support that syntax. You can concatenate the two loops `(for /l %%a in (1 1 5) do set "inputFile%a=1") & (for /l %%a in (15 1 20) do set "inputFile%a=1")& ...` or you can directly enumerate the elements (without the `/l`) `(for %%a in (1 2 3 4 5 15 16 17 18 19 20) do set "inputFile%a=1")& ...`

Comment: ok THANKS so much so far MC, my last question would be how to put this in on IF command....i want to check for one value whether it is in range 1 to 5 or 15 to 20 and delete if it is the case ...something like IF value in (1 to 5 ) or value in (15 to 20) delete filevalue

Comment: @sakal, the first code does not need numeric tests, as it checks for file name definition. For numeric tests, use the second code.

Comment: ok, but this part i dont understand at all, what happens here?: set "n=%~na" & set /a "n=!n:~9!">nul

Comment: i runthe command and it deletes all files, that is why i want to know the values for n....but i dont know how to echo n

Comment: @sakal, answer upated. `set "n=%~na"` retrieves the file name without extensions `set /a "n=!n:~9!">nul` extracts the number (strings start at index 0)

Comment: Thanks so much, is there a way to echo n to also see values for n? should it be echo !n! or echo %n% or how to achieve that?

Comment: thanks , what i noticed...the given solution deletes files between 5 and 15 , i wanted to delete the files between 1 and 5 and between 15 and 20 , as far as i have seen your solution realizes a logical AND , i need a logical OR....thanks

Comment: @sakal, answer updated, see the edited section. My fault, I was deleting what should be keep and keeping what should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Because you posted with the batch file tag I am giving you a batch command you can run from command line, and figure you will know how to modify it if needed for powershell.

The code below will delete the files as you want to do. It simply sets var G=5 and then at each iteration increments the number by 1 until G=20 is processed, then it stops. The G var increments the number in the file name with each iteration.

This just echoes the files so you can see it works. Change ECHO to DEL to delete the files.

```
    FOR /L %G IN (5,1,20) DO ECHO "C:\tmp\out\InputFile%G.csv"
```

If you are running this from a batch file, use @echo off and double the %marks like this

```
    @echo off
    FOR /L %%G IN (5,1,20) DO ECHO "C:\tmp\out\InputFile%%G.csv"
```

Comment: thanks but i wanted to be flexible with the number of files in the folder , so the command should delete all files , no matter how many there are with this command...20 files was just an example, it should also work for 100 files ....and additionally i should have mentioned earlier...i want to keep some sort of IF THEN ELSE structure in the command

Comment: @sakal. And you need all this in one nested command, right? I'm sure it can be done nicely. Others are better at that than I. I am editing the title again to reflect your needs.